# Timout - Async callback was not involved within 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimout.Timeout

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I tried to write a Jest and puppeteer code for e2e automation testing for a simple application in the react. The file can be found in https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-jest/blob/part2/js/index.test.js

I made some changes to the code which looks like this

```
test('Fetching success panel', async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 40,
    args: ['--window-size=1280,800']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(app);

  await page.click('input#firstName');
  await page.type('input#firstName', 'John');
  await page.click('input#lastName');
  await page.type('input#lastName', 'Doe');
  await page.click('input#password');
  await page.type('input#password', '123456abc');
  await page.click('input#confirmPassword');
  await page.type('input#confirmPassword', '123456abc');
  await page.click('input#email');
  await page.type('input#email', 'john@email.com');
  await page.click('button#formBtn');
  let successPanel = await page.waitForSelector('div.card-panel');
  expect(successPanel).toBeDefined();
  //const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  //const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await browser.close();
}, 10000);
```

For which I am trying to run npm test which shows the following error

```
FAIL js/index.test.js (19.551s)
  √ Validating first name field (3204ms)
  × Fetching success panel (10001ms)

  ● Fetching success panel

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      61 | // }, 10000);
      62 |
    > 63 | test('Fetching success panel', async () => {
         | ^
      64 |   browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      65 |     headless: false,
      66 |     slowMo: 40,

      at new Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Object.test (js/index.test.js:63:1)
```

So can anyone please let me know how to solve this problem. If any more details are required I am ready to share.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://github.com/americanexpress/jest-image-snapshot/issues/121#issuecomment-455375692

Comment: I am not able to find the puppeteer file configuration. So what should be done. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7AHtWR2Zyk => This is what I am trying. Can you please give me a detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it exactly as they described in the comment

```
let args = [];
args.push('--no-sandbox');
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 40,
   ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'], args}
  });
  let browser =  await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'], args});
```